# using @Embedabble with a foreign key and manyToMany relation

Tags: jpa, foreign-keys, persistence, jpa-2.0, entities

I wrote an example for the code i am trying to implement, i get an error with Constraint "Student_Teacher_FK" already exists.

the @embiddable class has a foreign key that is created twice with current code.

```
@Entity
public class Teacher {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "Name")
    private String name;

}

@Entity
public class Student{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "Name")
    private String name;

}

@Embeddable
public class StudentList implements Serializable {

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "Student_Teacher",
            joinColumns =
            @JoinColumn(name = "Student_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns =
            @JoinColumn(name = "Teacher_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    )
    @ForeignKey(name = "Student_Teacher_FK", inverseName = "Teacher_Student_FK")
    public List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();

}

@Entity
public class HistoryTeacher extends Teacher {
   @Embedded
   @NotNull
   private StudentList StudentList = new StudentList ();   
}

@Entity
public class LangTeacher extends Teacher {
   @Embedded
   @NotNull
   private StudentList StudentList = new StudentList ();    
}

@Entity
public class RetiredTeacher extends Teacher {
    // has no students
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@embeddable : Defines a class whose instances are stored as an intrinsic part of an owning entity and share the identity of the entity (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Embeddable.html)
As you are declaring it in 2 different entity, jpa will create associated association table (student-teacher) 2 times with associated fk, which is explicitely named, and so created 2 times too with the same name. Here is your error.

I don't think using @embeddable is appropriated for what you're intending to do. A student has is own existence and is not part of teacher itself (not an uml composition / black diamond) so it's not an embeddable entity. Student list should be held by teacher entity using a simple manyToMany association.

Comment: Hi Gab, so you suggest each class that extends teacher to have its many to many relation with student? could you explain more about your suggestion? thanks.

Comment: Well i suppose a teacher may always have a list of associated student. Retired one will simply have an empty list since no student will be any more associated with it. I don't really know how to explain it more. What kind of inheritance strategy did you choose ?

Comment: this is just a demo code, the retired teacher meant that must not have list of students... i cant change the inheritance diagram right now, it works well if i add the relation to Teacher class, but i must prevent some of the sub classes to have the list...

Comment: In this case, each concrete class will have to define the relationship when it needs it. Again, all of this depends of your business and the inheritance strategy you choose (http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.0/apache-openjpa-1.0.0/docs/manual/jpa_overview_mapping_inher.html#jpa_overview_mapping_inher_single) But for the example you gave, the right solution is to put the relationship in the parent teacher.